# Has this mathematically proven solipsism?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, solipsism

http://bc.upjp2.edu.pl/Content/5621/35_PDFsam_Ca%C5%82o%C5%9B%C4%87%20ze%20znakiem%20wodnym3.pdf

It's not so much the math as it is these things in the link:

2. More generally, there can be no deductive refutation of this solipsism
   employing only premises a committed solipsist would accept: all logically
   correct derivations from solipsistically true premises lead to conclusions
   that are solipsistically true as well. Any route to a successful refutation of
   solipsism must travel via nondeductive inferential paths.
3. Every solipsistic theory that is strict – as defined below – and axiomatic
   is the close translational analogue of an axiomatic nonsolipsistic theory. If
   the solipsist can axiomatize her nonsolipsistic theories, she can do the same
   with their solipsistic correlates.

"Any axiomatic theory and set of axioms for that theory in the non‑
solipsistic language can be carried over into the solipsistic language
as a theory with corresponding axioms, provided that the latter
theory is strict. Importantly, it is easy to argue – see the reply to
the third interpretation of the Private Language Argument – that
basic mathematical theories are all strict. Hence, a solipsist can
avail herself of, say, Peano/Dedekind Arithmetic together with its
familiar set of axioms."

These three parts of the link which when read together sounds to me like all paths lead to solipsism, though I'm very doubtful about my interpretation.

I just needed help understanding if he's saying what I think he's saying, if he's not then I can dump all this behind me and let it go. But I'm asking all over and haven't been able to find someone who either can or will do it.

It's at least 50 pages and I'm not sure what the math means in it to be honest. I don't think he proves solipsism true, just that it is internally consistent and can't be refuted, which isn't news.

Though if someone could explain the math I would be super joyful.

Comment: For this kind of work where a formal logic is invoked, look at what claims are encoded in the formal logic to lead to further derivations. The formal logic will probably have been verified and be valid, but the soundness of the of the encoded premises can be lacking. The formal logic may make the argument look formidable, but usually some premise(s) will be (very) questionable. Don't be fooled by the formal logic, it's only half the battle.

Comment: I actually don't have any idea where to start with this. I don't get the formal logic or what he is trying to say with solipsism. If it's just that one line at the end then I can live with it. But I tried reading through it and I couldn't make heads or tails of it except a few parts including what I shared.

Comment: In between the formal logic, try to find out the premises he uses, and see what you think of them. Ignore the formal logic. It's probably valid. The premises may not be good though.

Comment: The author doesn't seem to be trying to prove solipsism correct, just to formalize solipsistic reasoning.

Comment: There can be no deductive refutation of any X employing only premises a committed adherent of X would accept, as long as adherents of X are minimally careful to avoid inconsistency. So that particular conclusion seems to be a triviality not worth spending 50 pages on.

Comment: That’s what it seems to be leading to. But then you could just change the premises and leave the solipsist alone right? 

But then does the quote I wrote mean that everything leads to solipsism? Personally I think I’m wrong on that.

Comment: I do not see "all paths lead to solipsism". All I see is that if one is a solipsist then they can say so consistently and even throw in arithmetic for good measure, which is another triviality. Radical skeptics, nihilists, and even last thursdayists can do all of that too. To say something interesting, he'd have to lose the "deductiveness" and start from premises that are intuitively appealing and at least ostensibly non-solipsistic. Even Descartes and Wittgenstein did a better job on that while arguing *against* solipsism.

Comment: @Conifold So you understood that math he was writing? So the points I wrote above don't mean "all paths lead to solipsism"? To be honest that seems to be right. I thought he meant that if any axioms can be attribute to a solipsist as well (or they can use them) and solipsistic premises lead to solipsism, then that would mean any premise you use the solipsist can use and lead to solipsism, thus all paths would lead to solipsism.

Comment: He says essentially that most things non-solipsists say "formally" solipsists can "translate" into their language and hence incorporate into their position. After that it will, of course, "lead" to solipsism. There is some technical formalization to make that precise and substantiate it. The same is true of all sufficiently comprehensive and consistent philosophical positions with "most things" suitably specified. In and of itself, it no more leads to them than it leads to solipsism. Philosophical positions stand or fall on plausibility of informal arguments for their premises, not formalism.

Comment: @Conifold Ah thank you, I suspected my assessment was wrong but couldn’t pin it down as to how it was wrong. So it doesn’t lead to solipsism anymore than any else leads to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

From perusing his paper, I conclude tenuously that he claims to prove that a version of solipsism (which he defines) is internally consistent and cannot be refuted in a logically watertight way by arguments that are consistent with his version of solipsism. Fair enough. I am thinking of introducing a new philosophical outlook called Ocramism, the fundamental tenet of which is that a statement is true if and only if it is compatible with my views. Try to disprove that one.

It seems to me that solipsists must be really clever, because their minds are able to imagine other people coming up with answers on virtually any topic. Ooops, did I say 'solipsists'? Silly me!  I meant which ever of us is the real solipsist.

Comment: Yeah that does seem to be the case. Thought what of the quotes I mentioned? Part of me thinks it’s “all paths lead to solipsism” but I’m severely doubtful about my interpretation

Comment: @marco ocram, ever hear of the singing group, the Solip Sisters? There's only one of them but they can't decide which!

Comment: @nielsnielsen Ha!